# Linux repetedly scanning for Wireless networks

Tags: linux, wifi, embedded-linux, wpa

I am working on a Linux based IOT device that has a touch screen. I am using wpa_supplicant and then wpa_cli to manage the wireless network from my application.

What exactly happens during a wifi scan, technically?

What effects will the command scan_interval have on power usage, network link quality and performance?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww I am actually programming my device, and I need to consider the implications of architecting my software one way or the other.